# ValueError: Number of classes, 28, does not match size of target_names, 31. Try specifying the labels parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

Почему лезет эта ошибка и что с нею делать?

```js
# USAGE
# python train_simple_nn.py --dataset animals --model output/simple_nn.model --label-bin output/simple_nn_lb.pickle --plot output/simple_nn_plot.png

# импортируем бэкенд Agg из matplotlib для сохранения графиков на диск
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")

# подключаем необходимые пакеты
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from imutils import paths
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import random
import pickle
import cv2
import os

# создаём парсер аргументов и передаём их
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
 help="path to input dataset of images")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
 help="path to output trained model")
ap.add_argument("-l", "--label-bin", required=True,
 help="path to output label binarizer")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--plot", required=True,
 help="path to output accuracy/loss plot")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# инициализируем данные и метки
print("[INFO] loading images...")
data = []
labels = []

# берём пути к изображениям и рандомно перемешиваем
imagePaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"])))
random.seed(42)
random.shuffle(imagePaths)

# цикл по изображениям
for imagePath in imagePaths:
 # загружаем изображение, меняем размер на 32x32 пикселей (без учета
 # соотношения сторон), сглаживаем его в 32x32x3=3072 пикселей и
 # добавляем в список
 image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
 try:
  image = cv2.resize(image, (32, 32)).flatten()
 except:
  print('NOT OK')
  continue
 data.append(image)

 # извлекаем метку класса из пути к изображению и обновляем
 # список меток
 label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
 labels.append(label)

# масштабируем интенсивности пикселей в диапазон [0, 1]
data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)
print(data)
print(labels)
print(len(labels))
# разбиваем данные на обучающую и тестовую выборки, используя 75%
# данных для обучения и оставшиеся 25% для тестирования
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data,
 labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

# конвертируем метки из целых чисел в векторы (для 2х классов при
# бинарной классификации вам следует использовать функцию Keras
# “to_categorical” вместо “LabelBinarizer” из scikit-learn, которая
# не возвращает вектор)
lb = LabelBinarizer()
trainY = lb.fit_transform(trainY)
testY = lb.transform(testY)
print(lb.classes_)
print(len(lb.classes_))

# определим архитектуру 3072-1024-512-3 с помощью Keras
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1024, input_shape=(3072,), activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(512, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(len(lb.classes_), activation="softmax"))
# инициализируем скорость обучения и общее число эпох
INIT_LR = 0.01
EPOCHS = 75

# компилируем модель, используя SGD как оптимизатор и категориальную
# кросс-энтропию в качестве функции потерь (для бинарной классификации
# следует использовать binary_crossentropy)
print("[INFO] training network...")
opt = SGD(lr=INIT_LR)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
 metrics=["accuracy"])

# обучаем нейросеть
H = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY),
 epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=32)

# оцениваем нейросеть
print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
predictions = model.predict(testX, batch_size=32)
print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1),
 predictions.argmax(axis=1), target_names=lb.classes_))

# строим графики потерь и точности
N = np.arange(0, EPOCHS)
plt.style.use("ggplot")
plt.figure()
plt.plot(N, H.history["loss"], label="train_loss")
plt.plot(N, H.history["val_loss"], label="val_loss")
plt.plot(N, H.history["acc"], label="train_acc")
plt.plot(N, H.history["val_acc"], label="val_acc")
plt.title("Training Loss and Accuracy (Simple NN)")
plt.xlabel("Epoch #")
plt.ylabel("Loss/Accuracy")
plt.legend()
plt.savefig(args["plot"])

# сохраняем модель и бинаризатор меток на диск
print("[INFO] serializing network and label binarizer...")
model.save(args["model"])
f = open(args["label_bin"], "wb")
f.write(pickle.dumps(lb))
f.close()

score = model.evaluate(testX, testY, verbose=1)
print("\nTest score:", score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Данная ошибка говорит о том, что `testY` и `predictions` - содержат 28 уникальных классов, а при вызове `classification_report(..., target_names=lb.classes_)` в качестве имен классов вы передали список, содержащий 31 наименование.

Для начала уберите параметр `target_names=lb.classes_`, чтобы убедиться, что ошибка исчезла. А дальше ищите причину несовпадения размерностей.